# sklearn - Save train_test_split splits/states in multiply runs?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Python, pandas, jupyter, scikit-learn.

I need to:

- Make n **different** splits of a dataset.
- Do something to be able to **reproduce** any of them later - in **another** notebook/script.
- Elegant way would be nice.

Now I'm using sklearn train_test_split, but would be fine with alternatives. If I understand correctly random_state parameter can be used in the following way:

```
n = 10**6
while n > 0:
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state = n)

    #whatever I'm going to to with this split 
    n-=1
```

Then I expect to be able to reproduce the split. Can I dump the model to reproduces them in another notebook and is it effective?

**UPD**
I found the correct answer empirically. (Please, instruct me if there's a specific way to answer your own question).

Train test split can be dumped/loaded as a model.

```
joblib.dump(train_test_split, path)
my_train_test_split = joblib.load(path)
```

For more than one dataset. I use it twice within a loop, on two different datasets, passing unique random states. And I'm able to reproduce splits for each of the datasets with the loaded model. That's all I need.

Comment: list append ...search the key words list append for loop

Comment: when reading my answer, please consider that you asked for a way to Make n different splits of a dataset.
Save them to a file. If that was not what you meant, please edit

Comment: this sounds like doing k-fold cross-validation. maybe that is what you are looking for?

Comment: this sounds like doing k-fold cross-validation. maybe that is what you are looking for?

Comment: @NathanMcCoy updated, I found what I needed. Actually we're about a brutal way to achieve true joint distribution on a very small set (less than 500 samples). Split, train, get metrics, repeat 10^6 times. So k-fold looks like an alternative, but I can't see any advantages that far.

Comment: @ErroriSalvo sorry, my question indeed wasn't precise. The final goal is to be able to reproduce the split.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly what the random state parameter is for. If you call `training_test_split` on the same dataset with the same random state you achieve the same split every time. To prove it to yourself you can write a simple script to check

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = np.arange(25)
rs = 42
train, test = train_test_split(X,
                               test_size=0.3,
                               random_state=rs)
for i in range(10):
    new_train, new_test = train_test_split(X,
                                           test_size=0.3,
                                           random_state=rs)
    print(np.all(train == new_train), np.all(test == new_test))
```

**Output:**

```
(True, True)
(True, True)
(True, True)
(True, True)
(True, True)
(True, True)
(True, True)
(True, True)
(True, True)
(True, True)
```

Comment: Are the splits with different random state unique? Then, I suppose, I can dump it - i.e. `joblib.dump(train_test_split, some_path)` - and pray it will be fine with our brutal 10^6?

Comment: Yes however you can check that by changing the `rs` parameter in my code yourself ;). All you will need to save out is a list of the random states that you used, assuming that you're using the same data for each call.

Answer (score 0):

you could add

```
import cpickle as pkl # module for serialization
```

and within the loop

```
# put all the content in a dict
tostore=dict(zip(['X_train', 'X_test', 'y_train', 'y_test' ], [train, test, y_train, y_test))
# open a file with context manager
with open('REP'+str(n),'wb') as filestore: 
    pkl.dump(tostore,filestore) # write dict to file
```

This should guarantee persistence for all the required train/test sets.
You can load back your data using pkl.load().

However, I advise you to dump the trained model as well, as in principle each model might depend on other random number generator than you expect (depending on which ML framework you are using). If it was sklearn, you should be safe setting the random state when required.

Ideally a tuple of `fitted models, randomstate` together with the original full dataset should be ok.

Also, listing exact version numbers of all all the packages in use would be wise.